# Custom icon in a column header with custom sort functionality in ag-grid react

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

[Column header with sort icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beRt7.png)

Hello I am trying to implement a column header as shown in the picture. I can't figure out a way to implement this.

I am trying to add a sort icon in the column header and upon clicking that icon the grid should be sorted according to a custom logic.

There are two parts, adding the icon in the header and then giving the icon onClick  functionality. Any help how I can go about implementing this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Ag-grid has a built-in sorting functionality which you can customize it based on your requirements

There are 2 ways by which you can implement it

1. Enable the sorting for individual columns by adding -> **sortable: true**

```
const columnDefs = [
    { field: 'name', sortable: true },
    { field: 'age', sortable: true },
    { field: 'address' },
];
```

2.To enable sorting for all columns, set sorting in the default column definition.

```
const defaultColDef = {
    sortable: true
};

// If some fields doesn't need sort option, assign the value false to sortable
const columnDefs = [
    { field: 'name' },
    { field: 'age' },
    // suppress sorting on address column
    { field: 'address', sortable: false },
];
```

3. Custom sorting

```
const columnDefs = [
    {
        field: 'age',
        // simple number comparator
        comparator: (valueA, valueB, nodeA, nodeB, isDescending) => valueA - valueB
    },
    {
        field: 'name',
        // simple string comparator
        comparator: (valueA, valueB, nodeA, nodeB, isDescending) => {
            if (valueA == valueB) return 0;
            return (valueA > valueB) ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: I am trying to add a sort icon in the column header and upon clicking that icon the grid should be sorted according to custom logic.

I know how to implement plain custom sorting logic. Please check out the image link to get better understanding.